# Chrome Extensions: How does A Browser Action popup communicate with the active tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want a script running on my browser action popup to get information from the current active tab when invoked. It's not clear to me how to communicate between the two. Do I need a content script running on the active tab and a `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()` requesting info from it? What permissions should I ask for?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the communication between content-script and other scripts (background, browserAction, pageAction) goes via messages. So, on each side you have this kind of code:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    // process the request
    // reply as port.postMessage(data) if needed
  };
};
```